# Erro na requisição

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

Ola estou com um pequeno problema é o seguinte estou criando uma firebase cloud function que faz uma requisição aqui esta o codigo:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var axios = require('axios');
exports.get_video_info = functions.https.onCall(function(data){

  var url = "https://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id="+data.id;
  return axios.get(url)
});
```

Mas quando chamo a função aparece o seguinte erro no google cloud:

```
Unhandled error { Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN youtube.com:443
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:67:26)
  errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
  code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'youtube.com',
  host: 'youtube.com',
  port: 443,
  config: 
   { adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
     transformRequest: { '0': [Function: transformRequest] },
     transformResponse: { '0': [Function: transformResponse] },
     timeout: 0,
     xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
     xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
     maxContentLength: -1,
     validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
     headers: 
      { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'User-Agent': 'axios/0.18.0' },
     method: 'get',
     url: 'https://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=R3cbfZKfmkE',
     data: undefined },
  request: 
   Writable {
     _writableState: 
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        destroyed: false,
        decodeStrings: true,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: true,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     domain: 
      Domain {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        members: [] },
     _events: 
      { response: [Function: handleResponse],
        error: [Function: handleRequestError] },
     _eventsCount: 2,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _options: 
      { maxRedirects: 21,
        maxBodyLength: 10485760,
        protocol: 'https:',
        path: '/get_video_info?video_id=R3cbfZKfmkE',
        method: 'get',
        headers: [Object],
        agent: undefined,
        auth: undefined,
        hostname: 'youtube.com',
        port: null,
        nativeProtocols: [Object],
        pathname: '/get_video_info',
        search: '?video_id=R3cbfZKfmkE' },
     _ended: true,
     _ending: true,
     _redirectCount: 0,
     _redirects: [],
     _requestBodyLength: 0,
     _requestBodyBuffers: [],
     _onNativeResponse: [Function],
     _currentRequest: 
      ClientRequest {
        domain: [Object],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 6,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        _contentLength: 0,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        _header: 'GET /get_video_info?video_id=R3cbfZKfmkE HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nUser-Agent: axios/0.18.0\r\nHost: youtube.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
        _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
        agent: [Object],
        socketPath: undefined,
        timeout: undefined,
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/get_video_info?video_id=R3cbfZKfmkE',
        _ended: false,
        res: null,
        aborted: undefined,
        timeoutCb: null,
        upgradeOrConnect: false,
        parser: null,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _redirectable: [Circular],
        [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
     _currentUrl: 'https://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=R3cbfZKfmkE' },
  response: undefined }
```

Já não sei mais o que faço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso pode estar relacionado ao plano do Firebase Cloud. Existe uma limitação de acesso a APIs quando o plano é gratuito. Neste post se descreve um problema como o seu:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182121/error-getaddrinfo-eai-again

Uma das formas de contornar este problema sem ter que fazer o upgrade do plano seria trocar o endereço da API, ao invés de acessar os endpoints do domínio youtube.com, utilizar as API do domínio googleapis.com

No link do tutorial abaixo, feito este mês, se mostra como fazer isso. Neste link, se utilizou o PowerShell para acessar a API, mas, você pode considerar apenas os endereços que ele acessou e utilizar o Axios para fazer a comunicação

https://lazywinadmin.com/2019/04/retrieving_youtube_videos_information_with_powershell.html#

Comment: Depois de eu ver sua resposta eu fui pesquisar e no site do Google Cloud sobre o preço vi que no plano gratuito só pode fazer chamadas as APIs da Google